# Kotlin: share variable in abstract class between extending classes

Tags: java, kotlin, inheritance, architecture, abstract

I have an abstract class A of which the classes B and C are extending. 
I want to have a static variable in class A that I can get and set from B and C so that they access a shared value. 
Currently, using getters and setters B and C each have their own variable instance.

Honestly I don't care that much about good or bad practice, I just want to make it somehow work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `companion object` to simulate static variable:

```
abstract class A {

    companion object {
        var staticVariable: Int = 0
    }
}

class B : A() {
    fun updateStaticVariable() {
        staticVariable = 1
    }
}

class C : A() {
    fun updateStaticVariable() {
        staticVariable = 2
    }
}
```

To access it from another place:

```
val sv = A.staticVariable
if (sv == 0) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: A more concise alternative is a top-level variable — defined in the same file but outside any `class` definitions.